# Compiling freetype library on I386 (simulator) for iPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, ios6, freetype2

I'm trying to compile `FreeType2 2.5.3` as a static library on I386 arch, 
then use it on an *iPhone OpenGL* application.

I'm building the `.a` it with this script:

```
./configure '--without-bzip2' '--without-zlib' 'CFLAGS=-arch i386'
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a /Users/vlzvl/Desktop/libfreetype-i386.a
```

I'm not entirely sure but `iPhone Simulator` can run I386 arch library? should i build it on other arch instead (running `Mountain Lion 10.8.2) on Virtualbox with iOS 6.0 SDK and XCode 4.5` ?

Anyway, i'm then loading the library on *XCode* through `Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries` and use the `Other` option to locate it.

My app crashes on first freetype function, the `FT_Init_FreeType` with a `Signal SIGABRT` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded compiling my static freetype library for i386 arch using the following script (with a help of some SO answers and some folder changes eg. `/iPhonesimulator` instead of `/iPhoneOS`)

```
./configure '--without-bzip2' '--without-zlib' '--without-png' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' 'CFLAGS=-arch i386 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/'
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a /Users/vlzvl/Desktop/libfreetype-i386.a
```